# Найти длину каждого слова, количество цифр в каждом слове, количество гласных букв в каждом слове

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста!

Ввести текстовую строку с помощью функции gets, слова в строке отделяются пробелами
В каждом слове определить: 
1.Длину слова 
2.Количество цифр
3. Количество гласных прописных букв
Результат вывести в виде:

Input text:
 MAma2001     Papa1234056789
 Text: MAma2001     Papa1234056789

---

```
                slovo                len_slova        kol_cifr        kol_glas_bukv
```

---

```
          MAma200                    8                     4                      1
```

Papa1234056789                   14                   10                     2

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

char w[256], *p;
int c;
int lw=1, ld=0, lg=0;
    p = w;
    printf("input string: ");
    c = getchar();
    *p++ = c;
    printf("slovo\t\t\tlen_slova\tkol_cifr\tkol_glas_bukv\n",w,lw,ld,lg);
    while (c != '\n') {
        c = getchar();
        if (c ==' ' || c=='\n' ) {
            *p = '\0'; /* add null terminator */
            if (lw<15){
            printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",w,lw,ld,lg);
            }
            else{
            printf("%s\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",w,lw,ld,lg);
            }
            p = w;
            ld=0;
            lg=0;
            lw=0;
        }
        else {
            lw++;
            if (c>='0' && c<='9'){ld++;}
            if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='u' || c=='i' || c=='o'){lg++;}
            if (c=='A' || c=='E' || c=='U' || c=='I' || c=='O'){lg++;}
            *p++ = c;
        }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
input string: MAma2001 Papa1234056789
slovo                   len_slova       kol_cifr        kol_glas_bukv
MAma2001                8               4               2
Papa1234056789          14              10              2
```